# spring-data pagination real query

Tags: pagination, spring-data

I have a repository with a simple query with pagination :

```
Page<MyBean> findMyBeans(String name, Pageable pageable);
```

My question is :

The pagination will limit to 20 (by default) the query to the mongo (like a limit in mysql) or it will retrieve all data from mongo and retun only 20 results to the caller ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It will limit a cursor to 20. Specifically it would create a DBCursor with the value limit to 20 as next:

```
Cursor id=0, ns=test.myCollection, query={ }, numIterated=0, limit=100, readPreference=primary
```

This is the same if you use the [Java Mongo DB Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/java/) and declares a `DBCursor` as:

```
DBCursor myCursor=myCollection.find().limit(20);
```

So using MongoDB directly native cursor would be (it iterates in 20 to 20)(First call first 20, then 21-40, and so on):

```
Cursor cursor = myCollection.find();
cursor.limit(20);
```